# Multiple include(s) in analysis_options.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to combine two (or more) `analysis_options.yaml` files for my project but wasn't able to find a way how to do that.

This works:

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

...
```

This works too:

```
include: package:flutter/analysis_options_user.yaml # note different "base" lint rules

...
```

But I'd need something like this:

```
include:
  - package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml
  - package:flutter/analysis_options_user.yaml

...
```

...which results in following error:

> warning: The include file - package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml
>     - package:flutter/analysis_options_user.yaml
>
> in /home/.../analysis_options.yaml cannot be found. (include_file_not_found at [...] analysis_options.yaml:1)

Has anyone encountered/resolved same problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only include one analysis options file.

Plus `package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml` and `package:flutter/analysis_options_user.yaml` 
enforce different rules.

Example:

- Pedantic does not use `empty_statements`
- analysis_options_user.yaml uses it

Comment: kindly can you provide me with the document link for confirmation