# pedantic vs flutter_lint which package to use and can they also be combined?

Tags: flutter

I had been using [`pedantic`](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) but recently a new package [`flutter_lints`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lints) is launched. I know this is more of a recommended question, but which one should I use and can I combine any of them, although it [doesn't seem to be true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360923/multiple-includes-in-analysis-options-yaml) as of today, any other way (other than copying the rules of one and pasting in the `analysis_options.yaml` file)

This is for `pedantic`:

```dart
String s = "Hello"; // Bad 
var s = 'Hello'; // Good
```

This is for `flutter_lints`:

```dart
final s = "Hello"; // Bad
const s = "Hello"; // Good
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic) is deprecated, so use `package:flutter_lints` in flutter applications, and `package:lints` in dart applications:

> This package is deprecated.
>
> Before it was deprecated, it was the way to get analysis options
> matching those used internally at Google. This was useful because it
> was a good starting point for which lints to enable.
>
> **Instead, please see package:lints** which is the lint recommendation
> from the Dart team, **or package:flutter_lints which extends that for
> Flutter**. These are better than the Google lint set because they take
> into account the needs of all Dart users, not just Google engineers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying [very_good_analysis](https://pub.dev/packages/very_good_analysis) because it's very strict and the best in my personal opinion

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: no, I'm just an experienced flutter dev that has tried many linters and this one is the best imho

Comment: @AlexandruMariuti Thank you but the question wasn't about a package recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) and customize your `analysis_options.yaml`.
If you want to customize the settings, you must add the rules one by one in the file, you don't have alternatives (as far as I know).

For example this is my setup:

```
include: package:lint/analysis_options.yaml

analyzer:
  exclude:
    - "**/*.g.dart"
    - "**/*.freezed.dart"
    - "**/*.gr.dart"
    - "lib/l10n/messages*"
  
  strong-mode:
      implicit-casts: true
      implicit-dynamic: true
  
  errors: 
    # Causes false positives (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41571)
    top_level_function_literal_block: ignore
    avoid_classes_with_only_static_members: error
    sort_pub_dependencies: error
    use_key_in_widget_constructors: error
    always_use_package_imports: error
    sort_constructors_first: error
    prefer_const_constructors: error

linter:
  rules:
    avoid_classes_with_only_static_members: false
    sort_pub_dependencies: false
    use_key_in_widget_constructors: true
    always_use_package_imports: true
    prefer_const_constructors: true
    # Conflicts with the convention used by flutter, which puts `Key key`
    # and `@required Widget child` last.
    always_put_required_named_parameters_first: false
    package_api_docs: true
    slash_for_doc_comments: true
    sort_constructors_first: true
```

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned in my post, I already know how to do it.